# SSPI идентификация

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Делаю идентификацию и аутентификацию пользователя через SSPI.

Клиент и сервер находятся на разных компьютерах домена. Связь между клиентом и сервером через WinSock. Использую пакет `Negotiate`.

Проблема: при подключении клиента с WinXP на сервер Win2012 (он же контроллер домена) пользователь идентифицируется неправильно (как другой пользователь).

При коннектах на WinXP откуда угодно или при коннекте с WinXP на Win7 все работает корректно.

В чем может быть проблема?

**Основной цикл**

```
tcout << _T("Current user: ") << getCurrentUser() << std::endl;
char data[BUFFER_SIZE];
int len = 0;
if (isServer) {
    tcout << _T("Wait clients") << std::endl;
    SOCKET acc = accept_socket(socket);
    closesocket(socket);
    tcout << _T("Client accepted") << std::endl;
    socket = acc;
    auth = new ServerAuth();
    recvData(socket, data, len);
} else {
    connect_socket(socket, argv[1]);
    auth = new ClientAuth();
}
SECURITY_STATUS status = auth->auth(data, len);
while (status != SEC_E_OK || len > 0) {
    tcout << _T("ClientAuthCode: ") << auth->statusName(status) << std::endl;
    if (len) {
        sendData(socket, data, len);
        len = 0;
    }
    if (status != SEC_E_OK) {
        recvData(socket, data, len);
        status = auth->auth(data, len);
    }
}
tcout << _T("End authentification. Status: ") << auth->statusName(status) << std::endl;
if (isServer)
    tcout << _T("Connected user: ") << getUserName(auth->getUserToken()) << std::endl;
```

**Метод auth**

```c++
SECURITY_STATUS auth(void * data, int &len) {
    PSecBufferDesc inBufPtr = NULL;
    SecBufferDesc inBufDesc;
    SecBuffer inBuf;
    if (len) {
        inBufDesc.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;
        inBufDesc.cBuffers = 1;
        inBufDesc.pBuffers = &inBuf;

        inBuf.BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
        inBuf.cbBuffer = len;
        inBuf.pvBuffer = data;

        inBufPtr = &inBufDesc;
    }

    SecBufferDesc outBufDesc;
    SecBuffer outBuf;
    outBufDesc.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;
    outBufDesc.cBuffers = 1;
    outBufDesc.pBuffers = &outBuf;
    memset(&outBuf, 0, sizeof(outBuf));
    outBuf.BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;

    SECURITY_STATUS res = initContext(&context, inBufPtr, &outBufDesc);
    contextPtr = &context;
    switch (res) {
        case SEC_E_OK:
        case SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED:
            len = outBuf.cbBuffer;
            break;
        case SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE:
            len = 0;
            break;
        case SEC_I_COMPLETE_NEEDED:
            len = 0;
            res = SEC_E_OK;
        case SEC_I_COMPLETE_AND_CONTINUE:
            secCheck(CompleteAuthToken(contextPtr, &outBufDesc));
            len = outBuf.cbBuffer;
            break;
        default:
            throwSystemError(res);
    }
    memcpy(data, outBuf.pvBuffer, len);
    secCheck(FreeContextBuffer(outBuf.pvBuffer));
    return res;
}
```

**Два перекрытых метода initContext**

```c++
class ServerAuth: public CustomAuth {
protected:
    SECURITY_STATUS initContext(PCtxtHandle context, PSecBufferDesc inBuf, PSecBufferDesc outBuf) {
        DWORD attr;
        return AcceptSecurityContext(getCredHandle(), getContext(), inBuf,
            ISC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY | ISC_REQ_CONNECTION | ISC_REQ_ALLOCATE_MEMORY,
            SECURITY_NETWORK_DREP, context, outBuf, &attr, NULL
            );
    }
};

class ClientAuth: public CustomAuth {
protected:
    SECURITY_STATUS initContext(PCtxtHandle context, PSecBufferDesc inBuf, PSecBufferDesc outBuf) {
        DWORD attr;
        return InitializeSecurityContext(getCredHandle(), getContext(), NULL,
            ISC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY | ISC_REQ_CONNECTION | ISC_REQ_ALLOCATE_MEMORY,
            0, SECURITY_NETWORK_DREP, 
            inBuf, 0, context, outBuf, &attr, NULL
            );
    }
};
```

**Получение имени пользователя**

```c++
HANDLE getUserToken() {
    SecPkgContext_AccessToken token;
    secCheck(QueryContextAttributes(contextPtr, SECPKG_ATTR_ACCESS_TOKEN, &token));
    return token.AccessToken;
}

String getUserName(HANDLE token) {
    char data[BUFFER_SIZE];
    DWORD len;
    win32Check(GetTokenInformation(token, TokenUser, data, BUFFER_SIZE, &len));
    PSID sid = ((PTOKEN_USER)data)->User.Sid;
    win32Check(IsValidSid(sid));
    TCHAR login[BUFFER_SIZE];
    TCHAR domain[BUFFER_SIZE];
    len = BUFFER_SIZE;
    DWORD domLen = BUFFER_SIZE;
    SID_NAME_USE use;
    win32Check(LookupAccountSid(NULL, sid, login, &len, domain, &domLen, &use));
    String res = String(domain) + String(_T("\\")) + String(login);
    return res;
}
```

**И вывод**

- **Клиент**

  ```
  Current user: TESTDOMAIN\Oper
  ClientAuthCode: SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED
  Sended 63 bytes
  Received 290 bytes
  ClientAuthCode: SEC_E_OK
  Sended 208 bytes
  End authentification. Status: SEC_E_OK
  ```
- **Сервер**

  ```
  Current user: TESTDOMAIN\TestAdmin
  Wait clients
  Client accepted
  Received 63 bytes
  ClientAuthCode: SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED
  Sended 290 bytes
  Received 208 bytes
  End authentification. Status: SEC_E_OK
  Connected user: TESTDOMAIN\Administrator
  ```

Откуда берется `TESTDOMAIN\Administrator` если должен быть пользователь `TESTDOMAIN\Oper`

На всякий случай полный код программы

```js
// Client.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#define SECURITY_WIN32

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Sspi.h>
#include <Security.h>


#define PORT 9999
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096

typedef void* DATA;

//TCHAR errorBuf[256];

#ifndef UNICODE  
  #define String std::string
  #define tcout std::cout
  #define toString std::to_string
#else
  #define String std::wstring
  #define tcout std::wcout
  #define toString std::to_wstring
#endif

String errorStr(DWORD code) {
 LPTSTR errorBuf = NULL;
 int len = FormatMessage(
  FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, 
  NULL,
  code, 0, (LPTSTR)&errorBuf, 0, NULL);
 String res = errorBuf;
 LocalFree((HLOCAL)errorBuf);
 return res;
}

void throwSystemError(int error) {
 tcout << errorStr(error) << std::flush;
 std::exit(1);
}

void throwSocketError() {
 throwSystemError(WSAGetLastError());
}

void win32Check(BOOL res) {
 if (!res)
  throwSystemError(GetLastError());
}

int sockCheck(int res) {
 if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
  throwSocketError();
 return res;
}

void secCheck(SECURITY_STATUS status) {
 if (status != SEC_E_OK)
  throwSystemError(status);
}

class CustomAuth {
private:
 CredHandle credHandle;
 PCtxtHandle contextPtr;
 CtxtHandle context;

public:
 CustomAuth() {
  secCheck(AcquireCredentialsHandle(NULL, NEGOSSP_NAME, SECPKG_CRED_BOTH,
   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &credHandle, NULL));
  memset(&context, 0, sizeof(context));
  contextPtr = NULL; 
 }

 ~CustomAuth() {
  reset();
  FreeCredentialsHandle(&credHandle);
 }

 void reset() {
  if (contextPtr) {
   secCheck(DeleteSecurityContext(contextPtr));
   contextPtr = NULL;
  }
 }

 SECURITY_STATUS auth(void * data, int &len) {
  PSecBufferDesc inBufPtr = NULL;
  SecBufferDesc inBufDesc;
  SecBuffer inBuf;
  if (len) {
   inBufDesc.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;
   inBufDesc.cBuffers = 1;
   inBufDesc.pBuffers = &inBuf;

   inBuf.BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
   inBuf.cbBuffer = len;
   inBuf.pvBuffer = data;

   inBufPtr = &inBufDesc;
  }

  SecBufferDesc outBufDesc;
  SecBuffer outBuf;
  outBufDesc.ulVersion = SECBUFFER_VERSION;
  outBufDesc.cBuffers = 1;
  outBufDesc.pBuffers = &outBuf;
  memset(&outBuf, 0, sizeof(outBuf));
  outBuf.BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;

  SECURITY_STATUS res = initContext(&context, inBufPtr, &outBufDesc);
  contextPtr = &context;
  switch (res) {
   case SEC_E_OK:
   case SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED:
    len = outBuf.cbBuffer;
    break;
   case SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE:
    len = 0;
    break;
   case SEC_I_COMPLETE_NEEDED:
    len = 0;
    res = SEC_E_OK;
   case SEC_I_COMPLETE_AND_CONTINUE:
    secCheck(CompleteAuthToken(contextPtr, &outBufDesc));
    len = outBuf.cbBuffer;
    break;
   default:
    throwSystemError(res);
  }
  memcpy(data, outBuf.pvBuffer, len);
  secCheck(FreeContextBuffer(outBuf.pvBuffer));
  return res;
 }

 HANDLE getUserToken() {
  SecPkgContext_AccessToken token;
  secCheck(QueryContextAttributes(contextPtr, SECPKG_ATTR_ACCESS_TOKEN, &token));
  return token.AccessToken;
 }

 static String statusName(SECURITY_STATUS status) {
  switch (status) {
   case SEC_E_OK: return _T("SEC_E_OK");
   case SEC_I_COMPLETE_AND_CONTINUE: return _T("SEC_I_COMPLETE_AND_CONTINUE");
   case SEC_I_COMPLETE_NEEDED: return _T("SEC_I_COMPLETE_NEEDED");
   case SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED: return _T("SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED");
   case SEC_I_INCOMPLETE_CREDENTIALS: return _T("SEC_I_INCOMPLETE_CREDENTIALS");
   case SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE: return _T("SEC_E_INCOMPLETE_MESSAGE");
  default:
   return toString(status);
  }
 }

protected:
 virtual SECURITY_STATUS initContext(PCtxtHandle context, PSecBufferDesc inBuf, PSecBufferDesc outBuf) = 0;

 PCredHandle getCredHandle() {
  return &credHandle;
 }

 PCtxtHandle getContext() {
  return contextPtr;
 }
};

class ServerAuth: public CustomAuth {
protected:
 SECURITY_STATUS initContext(PCtxtHandle context, PSecBufferDesc inBuf, PSecBufferDesc outBuf) {
  DWORD attr;
  return AcceptSecurityContext(getCredHandle(), getContext(), inBuf,
   ISC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY | ISC_REQ_CONNECTION | ISC_REQ_ALLOCATE_MEMORY,
   SECURITY_NETWORK_DREP, context, outBuf, &attr, NULL
   );
 }
};

class ClientAuth: public CustomAuth {
protected:
 SECURITY_STATUS initContext(PCtxtHandle context, PSecBufferDesc inBuf, PSecBufferDesc outBuf) {
  DWORD attr;
  return InitializeSecurityContext(getCredHandle(), getContext(), NULL,
   ISC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY | ISC_REQ_CONNECTION | ISC_REQ_ALLOCATE_MEMORY,
   0, SECURITY_NETWORK_DREP, 
   inBuf, 0, context, outBuf, &attr, NULL
   );
 }
};

SOCKET init_socket() {
 WSADATA data;
 int code = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &data);
 if (code)
  throwSystemError(code);
 SOCKET res = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
 if (res == INVALID_SOCKET)
  throwSocketError();
 return res;
}

void connect_socket(SOCKET socket, char * host) {
 sockaddr_in addr;
 addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
 hostent * hostEnt = gethostbyname(host);
 if (!hostEnt)
  throwSocketError();
 addr.sin_addr.S_un =  ((in_addr *)hostEnt->h_addr_list[0])->S_un;
 memset(addr.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(addr.sin_zero));
 sockCheck(connect(socket, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)));
}

SOCKET accept_socket(SOCKET socket) {
 sockaddr_in addr;
 addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
 addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr =  0;
 memset(addr.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(addr.sin_zero));
 sockCheck(bind(socket, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)));
 sockCheck(listen(socket, SOMAXCONN));
 SOCKET res = accept(socket, NULL, NULL);
 if (res == INVALID_SOCKET)
  throwSocketError();
 return res;
}

void sendData(SOCKET socket, char * data, int len) {
 sockCheck(send(socket, (char*)&len, sizeof(len), 0));
 if (len)
  sockCheck(send(socket, data, len, 0));
 tcout << __T("Sended ") << len << _T(" bytes") << std::endl;
}

void _recvData(SOCKET socket, char * data, int len) {
 int read = sockCheck(recv(socket, data, len, 0));
 if (read != len)
  throwSystemError(ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES);
}

void recvData(SOCKET socket, char * data, int &len) {
 _recvData(socket, (char*)&len, sizeof(len));
 if (len)
  _recvData(socket, data, len);
 tcout << __T("Received ") << len << _T(" bytes") << std::endl;
}

String getUserName(HANDLE token) {
 char data[BUFFER_SIZE];
 DWORD len;
 win32Check(GetTokenInformation(token, TokenUser, data, BUFFER_SIZE, &len));
 PSID sid = ((PTOKEN_USER)data)->User.Sid;
 win32Check(IsValidSid(sid));
 TCHAR login[BUFFER_SIZE];
 TCHAR domain[BUFFER_SIZE];
 len = BUFFER_SIZE;
 DWORD domLen = BUFFER_SIZE;
 SID_NAME_USE use;
 win32Check(LookupAccountSid(NULL, sid, login, &len, domain, &domLen, &use));
 String res = String(domain) + String(_T("\\")) + String(login);
 return res;
}

String getCurrentUser() {
 TCHAR buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
 DWORD len = BUFFER_SIZE;
 win32Check(GetUserNameEx(NameSamCompatible, buf, &len));
 return buf;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
 std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
 bool isServer = argc < 2;
 SOCKET socket = init_socket();
 CustomAuth * auth;
    tcout << _T("Current user: ") << getCurrentUser() << std::endl;
 char data[BUFFER_SIZE];
 int len = 0;
 if (isServer) {
  tcout << _T("Wait clients") << std::endl;
  SOCKET acc = accept_socket(socket);
  closesocket(socket);
  tcout << _T("Client accepted") << std::endl;
  socket = acc;
  auth = new ServerAuth();
  recvData(socket, data, len);
 } else {
  connect_socket(socket, argv[1]);
  auth = new ClientAuth();
 }
 SECURITY_STATUS status = auth->auth(data, len);
 while (status != SEC_E_OK || len > 0) {
  tcout << _T("ClientAuthCode: ") << auth->statusName(status) << std::endl;
  if (len) {
   sendData(socket, data, len);
   len = 0;
  }
  if (status != SEC_E_OK) {
   recvData(socket, data, len);
   status = auth->auth(data, len);
  }
 }
 tcout << _T("End authentification. Status: ") << auth->statusName(status) << std::endl;
 if (isServer)
  tcout << _T("Connected user: ") << getUserName(auth->getUserToken()) << std::endl;

 delete auth;
 closesocket(socket);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Используйте `QueryContextAttributes(ctx, SECPKG_ATTR_NAMES, ...)` чтобы получить имя пользователя контекста (после хендшейка). Можете так же вызвать обычный `GetUserName` под имперсонализацией с этим контекстом, это тоже вернет правильное имя (но только если разрешите в AD делегирование).

Comment: @mega `SECPKG_ATTR_NAMES` возвращает то же неправильное имя. Кроме того, конечная задача получить не имя, а SID

Comment: Вы на стороне клиента и сервера выводите в консоль имя пользователя. Может сразу и ошибку найдёте. В любом случае - полезно при диагностике.

Comment: а `SID` из контекста получить оч. просто - используйте связку: `QuerySecurityContextToken(ctx, &hToken)`, `GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, ...)` и `CloseHandle(hToken)`. Но для начала разберитесь с юзером.

Comment: @mega Еще раз проблема в том что на сервере **некорректно идентифицируется** пользователь. Причем в одном единственном случае при коннекте с WinXP на Win2012. Я **знаю** как получить сиды и имена. Я спрашиваю какие могут быть предпосылки для **неправильной** идентификации

Comment: Ок, еще раз: выведите в лог имена пользователей, под которыми запускаете клиент и сервер. За Вас это ни кто не сделает. Ошибку за Вас тоже ни кто искать не будет. Предпосылка для неправильной идентификации: **неправильно выбранные AD-пользователи, под которыми Вы запускаете свое ПО** ))

Comment: @mega Добавил в вопрос текущих пользователей

Comment: Не Ваш случай: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/da4a8ce8-12d7-4083-850f-5ec1362d6db7/client-user-authentication-with-sspi-via-ntlm-may-report-a-wrong-user-name?forum=windowssecurity ?

Comment: @isnullxbh Оно самое. Но там тоже без ответа

Comment: ```This works fine under normal conditions, but if the client Windows already has a network connection to the server with a different user (e.g. user “B”) this user is reported at step 10 instead of the current client user (“A”).``` - данное утверждение так же справедливо в Вашем случае?

Comment: @isnullxbh Нет. Я на клиентской машине захожу в систему и все действия произвожу от этого конкретного пользователя